# Accessing local files from Progressive Web App while offline on a mobile device

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, onedrive, indexeddb

I am building an Angular Progressive Web App for a client attempting to achieve the following:

1. Client manages some sort of shared folder/repository that contains a set of documents.
2. The consumer of this device has a mobile device -- iOS, Android, Windows (it is a BYOD environment)
3. These mobile devices all contain an application, say OneDrive for Business. That syncs with this shared folder.
4. The PWA works offline and needs to have access to these documents for viewing/playback while in the field hence why they must be available on the device in local storage or browser storage somehow.
5. Is there a way to force OneDrive (or any other storage option) to make these documents available offline without needing to manually go to the folder and tap "Make Available Offline"?

I found [this](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/203456-best-way-to-do-gpo-for-folder-redirection-sync) document regarding Microsoft Group Policy Objects but it seems to require a mobile device management system so the client can force their employees to have OneDrive installed and potentially? sync and download the documents for offline usage without their manual effort.

Also, I know [PWA offer browser storage using IndexedDB](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/web-storage/offline-for-pwa), but the guarantee that enough browser storage is available cannot be assumed as we aren't sure how much data the files will require. This is also a deterrent when "forcing" the files down to the device storage as the device may not have enough local storage.

Lastly, are there any other approaches

Comment: Visit https://whatwebcando.today/ with the target devices. Chromium browsers (Chrome & Edge) support the File System API. I don't think Safari is there yet.
As for accessing Cloud FIle Storage like OneDrive, G Drive, etc I don't know how that might work. If they are mapped to a folder sure. 
We just got the File system API due to security concerns & I have not played much with it yet.

Comment: After 8 months of your question, I'm curious if you found an answer to it.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into Capacitor JS that Ionic has built to help with local files for PWA scenarios. https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/filesystem The only issue is OneDrive, like many other applications store files in their own secure folders with the new security protocols with iOS and Android now. You could save the files via filesystem API and store them locally. It's something we are doing with our PWA.